# CSV File not passing from input

Tags: php, html, csv

test.php

```
<form action="test2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="csv_file" accept=".csv">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

test2.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if ($_FILES["csv_file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["csv_file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["csv_file"]["name"] . "<br />";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["csv_file"]["type"] . "<br />";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["csv_file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["csv_file"]["tmp_name"];
  } 
}

?>
```

When I am submitting a csv file. The test2.php page is getting an error

undefined index: csv_file.
Please Check.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the enctype tag

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

## edit

in your case:

```
<form action="test2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="csv_file" accept=".csv">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Nope still not getting the answer.

Comment: What is the output of `$_FILES["csv_file"]["error"]`